# Which functions of characteristic functions are characteristic functions?

Tags: probability-theory, self-learning, characteristic-functions

I have a basic question regarding characteristic functions:

> If $\phi(t)$ is a characteristic function of some random  variable $X$ , then is it necessary for
>
> 1. $\sqrt{\phi(t)}$
> 2. $|\phi(t)|$
>
> to be the characteristic function of some other random variable?

I need some help to start .

Comment: Bochner’s theorem: An arbitrary function $φ : \mathbb R → \mathbb C$ is the characteristic function of some random variable if and only if $φ$ is (1) positive definite, (2) continuous at the origin, and (3) if  $φ(0) = 1$.

Comment: For 1.: How do you define the square root on complex numbers?

Comment: @JimmyR. Why did you delete your answer?\

Comment: @JimmyR. At least provide the answer for the second part.

Comment: It was false. You cannot verify convexity. It is called Polya's theorem, just check [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Characteristic_function_(probability_theory)#Criteria_for_characteristic_functions)

Comment: @JimmyR. Can you please explain what you mean by **positive definite** function?

Comment: I can give you the definition from my book, but I think it is practically impossible to verify (as is also mentioned in the link I posted). For any $t_1, \dots, t_n \in \mathbb R$ and any $z_1, \dots, z_n\in \mathbb C$ $$\sum_{i=1}^n\sum_{j=1}^nz_i\varphi(t_i-t_j)\overline{z_j}\ge0$$ By the way $|\varphi(t)|^2$ is a characteristic function (see link again).

Comment: @JimmyR. $|\phi(t)^2|$ is easy, just difference of two iid random variables. But I am more concerned about just $|\phi(t)|$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The function $\varphi\colon t\mapsto\cos t$ is the characteristic function of a random variable taking the values $-1$ and $1$ with probability $1/2$. However, [$\left|\varphi\right|$ is not a characteristic function](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/122471/is-it-a-characteristic-function).

Note that since $ \left|\varphi\right|^2$ is a characteristic function (as noted by Qwerty, of the difference of two i.i.d. random variable with characteristic function $\varphi$), this also proves that the square root of a non-negative characteristic function does not need to be a characteristic function.

Comment: My bad:I got a bit confused with your notation. In your first line did you mean that $\phi(t)$ is a characteristic function$\implies\phi(\cos(t))$ is a characteristic function?

Comment: My notations are standard, I think. The function $\varphi$ is defined by $\varphi(t)=\cos t$.

Comment: Yeah sure. Fine. I said my bad.. Anyways, thanks for the clarification